# How to write an S3 formula method for a statistical model object in R

Tags: r, oop, multivariate-testing

I have a function that carries out Box's M test for equality of covariance
matrices in a multivariate linear model.  I'd like to turn it into an S3 generic function with a formula method, which is the most natural interface.

The complete current code is at https://gist.github.com/friendly/749b5a69a067e02b87dd.  I could paste it all in here, but perhaps that link
is sufficient.

I don't understand a lot of the magic used in functions that access model object components.  I used as a template the code I found in `leveneTest` in the `car` package, that solves a similar problem for univariate models.

Here is a quick test using the default method `boxM.default` :

```
data(iris)
res <- boxM(iris[, 1:4], iris[, "Species"])
res
```

which gives the desired result:

```
>     data(iris)
>     res <- boxM(iris[, 1:4], iris[, "Species"])
>     res

        Box's M-test for Homogeneity of Covariance Matrices

data:  iris[, 1:4]
Chi-Sq (approx.) = 140.94, df = 20, p-value < 2.2e-16
>
```

When I try to call the formula method `boxM.formula` directly, it also works, giving the same output as above.

```
boxM( cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data=iris)
```

However, this test of the `boxM.lm` method  fails:

```
> iris.mod <- lm(cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data=iris)
> boxM(iris.mod)
Error in cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) : 
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found
> traceback()
8: cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
7: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
6: eval(predvars, data, env)
5: model.frame.default(form, data)
4: model.frame(form, data) at boxM.R#59
3: boxM.formula(formula(y), data = model.frame(y), ...) at boxM.R#76
2: boxM.lm(iris.mod) at boxM.R#2
1: boxM(iris.mod)
>
```

I think I understand why it fails --- something to do with the environment for finding the variables in the `model.frame()`, but not how to correct it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You designed your `boxM` function can take an `lm` object as an input.  The implementation tries to extract the formula and the model.frame from the `lm` and reuse them with `boxM.formula`.

It seems the reason why this did not work out is because `model.frame(iris.mod)` does not return the original `data.frame` but a 2-column data.frame where the 1st column contains the matrix of left-hand side variables, and the 2nd the vector of the right-hand side.  You can check this by

```
class(model.frame(iris.mod))
dim(model.frame(iris.mod))
names(model.frame(iris.mod))
model.frame(iris.mod)[,1]
model.frame(iris.mod)[,2]
```

Since `model.frame(iris.mod)` already parsed the data into the computable format, you can apply `boxM.default` instead of `boxM.formula` when an `lm` object is the input.  For example, this seems to work:

```
boxM.default(Y = model.frame(iris.mod)[,1], 
             group = model.frame(iris.mod)[,2])

#    Box's M-test for Homogeneity of Covariance Matrices

#data:  model.frame(iris.mod)[, 1]
#Chi-Sq (approx.) = 140.94, df = 20, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: That is a very good explanation, and perhaps I could call `boxM.default` directly.  A colleague gave me a more general solution.  I post it as an answer below to complete this thread.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague who solved this said, "You're getting bitten by nonstandard evaluation."

Here is a solution that works, and is more generally in accord with S3 methods for model objects.  It finds the `data` in the environment of the
model formula.

```
boxM.lm <- function(y, ...) {
  data <- getCall(y)$data
  y <- if (!is.null(data)) {
    data <- eval(data, envir = environment(formula(y)))
    update(y, formula(y), data = data)
  }
  else update(y, formula(y))

  boxM.formula(formula(y), data=eval(data, envir = environment(formula(y))), ...)
}
```